# Find 3 in a row letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, character, letter

I need to find if one field contain 3 letters in a row:
Examples:

```
123abv31231 - Correct
abc12314121 - Correct
asdsadsad12 - Correct
98381233abc - Correct
123123ab123 - Not Correct
```

Doesn't matter where is the 3 characters. It's only matter they must be at least 3 in a row.
I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the operator [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select * from tablename
where col like '%[a-z][a-z][a-z]%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ff6c00c273f9fff05dad27e974abcec).
Results:

```
> | col         |
> | :---------- |
> | 123abv31231 |
> | abc12314121 |
> | asdsadsad12 |
> | 98381233abc |
```